# jsp control server side on form

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, servlets

I want compare to the data sent with all data in the db. this coce compare the date insert only with the last row. how can I compare with all row in the db?
................................................................................................

```
String sData= request.getParameter("idatadata");
        String sAzienda= request.getParameter("idazienda");
        String sCommessa= request.getParameter("idcommessa");



        String date = "";
        String company = "";
        String order = "";




        Connect con = new Connect();

        try {

            Connection connection = con.createConnection();

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            String sql ="SELECT * FROM table";

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

            while(resultSet.next()) {
            date = resultSet.getString("iddata");
            company = resultSet.getString("idazienda");
            order = resultSet.getString("idcommessa");

            }

            if((sData.equals(date) && sAzienda.equals(company)) && sCommessa.equals(order)) {
            out.print("already sent");
            con.closeConnection(connection);

            } 

            else {

            DbConnect.insertInDb(connection, sData, sOre, sMinuti, sAzienda, sCommessa, sRifInterno);
            dbc.closeConnection(connection);

            response.getWriter().append("ok! ");

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: do it with the query: `select count(*) from table where iddata = ? and idazienda = ? and idcommessa = ?`. If the query returns 0 results, the data is not already in the db. Also, if you want to do it the way you did, your check should be inside the `while` loop

Comment: Use query to check data exists in db. If you want search use like keyword of sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are checking only the last row, is that your while loop keeps overwriting your local variables each time you retrieve a row:

```
while(resultSet.next()) {
    // these lines overwrite the local vars for each row
    date = resultSet.getString("iddata");
    company = resultSet.getString("idazienda");
    order = resultSet.getString("idcommessa");
}
```

But you don't actually check the local vars inside the loop before moving on to the next row from the db. You should add the check into the loop:

```
while(resultSet.next()) {
    date = resultSet.getString("iddata");
    company = resultSet.getString("idazienda");
    order = resultSet.getString("idcommessa");

    // add your check here
    if((sData.equals(date) && sAzienda.equals(company)) && sCommessa.equals(order)) {
        out.print("already sent");
        break;
    } 
}
```

Preferably, just perform a select based on the data you are looking for. If you get no results, then the data isn't in the db. This method is much more efficient. If you do decide to go down this path (which is a good idea), use a prepared statement so that you don't introduce a SQL injection vulnerability into your code.

Comment: Thanks! now work. For other method u have a simple example?